# What is the best way to initialize a SortOrder column (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3) where there are multiple groups based on another field?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of list items. There is a ListID column used as an identifier to group the list items together. Is there a sane way to give every item a sort order, starting at 0 per list and incremental by one per item.

Basically, I need to populate the following SortOrder Column values for a large number of entries/ListIDs.

```
ID    ListID    SortOrder
1     1         0
2     0         0
3     1         1
4     0         1
5     1         2
6     0         2
7     2         0
8     2         1
9     2         2
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher, the ROW_NUMBER() function will do the trick.

Comment: The code you have pasted is for MySQL, not SQL Server

Comment: Woops, I didnt even notice that, I was just looking around because I had no idea where to start. I assumed I could use ROW_NUMBER() but I am not/was not sure if it was possible to do it in groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `PARTITION` on the `ListId` field for this:

```
Select   Id, ListId, 
         Row_Number() Over (Partition By ListId Order By Id) -1 As SortOrder
From     YourTable
Order By Id
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! What does the -1 do?

Comment: @Marie `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns an incrementing number to the records based on the `PARTITION` and `ORDER` defined in the `OVER` statement.  The numbers assigned start at `1`, so the `-1` portion is to get the assigned numbers to start at `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListId Order By id) as new_SortOrder
      FROM tableName
     )
UPDATE toupdate a
    SET sortorder = new_sort_order;
```

SQL Server has the nice ability to update a subquery or CTE under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to persist the order of lists containing items that are shared between lists? If so, perhaps variations on this schema would work for you.

```
Item
id    label
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D

List
id    listName
1     abc list
2     cbd list
3     aaa list

ListMembership
id    listId   itemId   order
1     1        1        1
2     1        2        2
3     1        3        3
4     2        2        2
5     2        3        1
6     2        4        3
7     3        1        1
8     3        1        2
9     3        1        3
```

usage:

```
select i.label from listMembership as lm
   join Item as i on i.id=lm.itemId
   where lm.listId=2
   order by lm.order
```

yields:

```
label
C
B
D
```

Comment: I have a good schema (that basically looks like that). My problem is that I need to back fill old data and I need to give everything a sort order that matches the old structure